# How do I create a event in websockets php?

Tags: php, javascript, websocket

I am testing out some websockets and I have a problem with creating some triggers/events.

I am not sure if this is possible at all but I just want to try.

So i've downloaded an example and i am currently just fooling around with it

This is what the server.php looks like:

```
<?php
include("C:\wamp\www\social\index.php"); 
// prevent the server from timing out
set_time_limit(0);

// include the web sockets server script (the server is started at the far bottom of this    file)
require 'class.PHPWebSocket.php';

// when a client sends data to the server
function wsOnMessage($clientID, $message, $messageLength, $binary) {
global $Server;

$Server->log('received message from ' . $Server->wsClients[$clientID]['user']);

$ip = long2ip( $Server->wsClients[$clientID][6] );

// check if message length is 0
if ($messageLength == 0) {
    $Server->wsClose($clientID);
    return;
}

//The speaker is the only person in the room. Don't let them feel lonely.
if ( sizeof($Server->wsClients) == 1 ){
    $item = wire('pages')->get('template=item');
    $Server->wsSend($clientID, "There isn't anyone else in the room, but I'll  still listen to you. --Your Trusty Server");
    $Server->wsSend($clientID, $clientID);
}
else
    //Send the message to everyone but the person who said it
    foreach ( $Server->wsClients as $id => $client )
        if ( $id != $clientID ){
            $Server->wsSend($id, "Visitor $clientID ($ip) said   \"$message\"  ");
        }
}

// when a client connects
function wsOnOpen($clientID)
{
global $Server;
$ip = long2ip( $Server->wsClients[$clientID][6] );
$Server->wsClients[$clientID]['user'] = wire('user')->name;
$Server->log( "$ip ($clientID) has connected. Username: " . $Server-   >wsClients[$clientID]['user'] );

//Send a join notice to everyone but the person who joined
foreach ( $Server->wsClients as $id => $client )
    if ( $id != $clientID ){
        $Server->wsSend($id, "Visitor $clientID ($ip) has joined the room.");
    }
}

// when a client closes or lost connection
function wsOnClose($clientID, $status) {
global $Server;
$ip = long2ip( $Server->wsClients[$clientID][6] );

$Server->log( "$ip ($clientID) has disconnected." );

//Send a user left notice to everyone in the room
foreach ( $Server->wsClients as $id => $client )
    $Server->wsSend($id, "Visitor $clientID ($ip) has left the room.");
}

function wsOnTest($clientID, $status) {
global $Server;
$ip = long2ip( $Server->wsClients[$clientID][6] );

$Server->log("Custom message");

//Send a user left notice to everyone in the room
foreach ( $Server->wsClients as $id => $client )
    $Server->wsSend($id, "Custom message");
}

// start the server 
$Server = new PHPWebSocket();
$Server->bind('message', 'wsOnMessage');
$Server->bind('open', 'wsOnOpen');
$Server->bind('close', 'wsOnClose');
$Server->bind('test', 'wsOnTest');
// for other computers to connect, you will probably need to change this to your LAN IP        or external IP,
// alternatively use: gethostbyaddr(gethostbyname($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']))
$Server->wsStartServer('127.0.0.1', 9300);

?>
```

And this is the index.html with a simple chat application. As you can see in both the server.php and this file i've tried to fool around with creating a event, or function called test.

```
    <!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset='UTF-8' />
    <style>
        input, textarea {border:1px solid #CCC;margin:0px;padding:0px}

        #body {max-width:800px;margin:auto}
        #log {width:100%;height:400px}
        #message {width:100%;line-height:20px}
    </style>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="fancywebsocket.js"></script>
    <script>
        var Server;

        function log( text ) {
            $log = $('#log');
            //Add text to log
            $log.append(($log.val()?"\n":'')+text);
            //Autoscroll
            $log[0].scrollTop = $log[0].scrollHeight - $log[0].clientHeight;
        }

        function send( text ) {
            Server.send( 'message', text );
        }

        function test( text ){
            Server.send('test', text);
        }

        $(document).ready(function() {
            log('Connecting...');
            Server = new FancyWebSocket('ws://127.0.0.1:9300');

            $('#message').keypress(function(e) {
                if ( e.keyCode == 13 && this.value ) {
                    log( 'You: ' + this.value );
                    send( this.value );
                    test( this. value);

                    $(this).val('');
                }
            });

            //Let the user know we're connected
            Server.bind('open', function() {
                log( "Connected." );
            });

            //OH NOES! Disconnection occurred.
            Server.bind('close', function( data ) {
                log( "Disconnected." );
            });

            //Log any messages sent from server
            Server.bind('message', function( payload ) {
                log( payload );
            });

            Server.bind('test', function( payload ) {
                log( payload );
            });

            Server.connect();
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id='body'>
        <textarea id='log' name='log' readonly='readonly'></textarea><br/>
        <input type='text' id='message' name='message' />
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

And to be complete, the fancywebsocket.js

```
var FancyWebSocket = function(url)
{
    var callbacks = {};
    var ws_url = url;
    var conn;

    this.bind = function(event_name, callback){
        callbacks[event_name] = callbacks[event_name] || [];
        callbacks[event_name].push(callback);
        return this;// chainable
    };

    this.send = function(event_name, event_data){
        this.conn.send( event_data );
        return this;
    };

    this.connect = function() {
        if ( typeof(MozWebSocket) == 'function' )
            this.conn = new MozWebSocket(url);
        else
            this.conn = new WebSocket(url);

        // dispatch to the right handlers
        this.conn.onmessage = function(evt){
            dispatch('message', evt.data);
        };

        this.conn.onclose = function(){dispatch('close',null)}
        this.conn.onopen = function(){dispatch('open',null)}
    };

    this.disconnect = function() {
        this.conn.close();
    };

    var dispatch = function(event_name, message){
        var chain = callbacks[event_name];
        if(typeof chain == 'undefined') return; // no callbacks for this event
        for(var i = 0; i < chain.length; i++){
            chain[i]( message )
        }
    }
};
```

So How do i make an event just like message, for example post or something, or do i need to send array's (json) with information in the json which i rather not...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: For PHP I'd recommend you use http://socketo.me for a WebSocket solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hate to say it, but you probably should use JSON. The websocket protocol does not define the structure of the payload, so there is no "websocket" way to do this. But this has been done before in the [WAMP Standard](http://wamp.ws/spec), and they indeed did it with JSON, specifically a JSON array with the first item identifying the message type, e.g. the WELCOME message:

```
[ TYPE_ID_WELCOME , sessionId , protocolVersion, serverIdent ]
```

I think a more flexible implementation (which you have alluded to) would be something like

```
{"name": "overTheLine", "message": "Mark it 8, Dude."}
```

so you can do something like

```
// when a client sends data to the server
function wsOnMessage($clientID, $message, $messageLength, $binary) {
    $messageObj = json_decode($message);
    if (property_exists($messageObj, 'name') 
        and property_exists($messageObj, 'message') 
        and is_callable($messageObj->name)) {
        $messageObj->name($messageObj->message);
    }
...
}

// over the line response
function overTheLine($msg) {
    return "Mark it zero!";
}
```

and likewise on the client.